# Build a report in Apache Camel to measure transaction times

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I want to make some performance tests on my Camel app (I'm using Spring Boot for development) and build a report based on the time that each transaction took to finish, but I'm not quite sure what will be the best approach (first time doing something like this).
This app is layered in three parts: each part will publish a message to a JMS queue, so the next part can pick it up. So, I know that I can get the elapsed time for each Exchange like this:

```
List<MessageHistory> historyList = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.MESSAGE_HISTORY, List.class);
for (MessageHistory history : historyList) {
   history.getElapsed();
}
```

But, as I will have three different parts inside the app I will get three different Exchanges. Each message coming inside the app will have an ID inside the payload so maybe I can group each transaction using that (unless there is a more Camel-oriented way to do it that I'm not aware of).

I can write something custom to make the report I suppose, but I'm wondering if maybe there are some frameworks that I can use.

Any recommendations are appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to capture the total time it took for the message to traverse in your application. If so, you can use camel interceptors.
You can capture the starting time using the FromInterceptor, save the time in a property, and get the end time using the sendToEndPoint interceptor. Calculate the time it took for the message to travel